# DCDIAG VerifyEnterpriseReferences test failed on PDC

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, dfs-r, active-directory

I have two domain controllers both server 2008, and the domain function level has been raised to 2008. We migrated from a single dc running server 2008 previously. If I run :

`dcdiag /v /c /d /e /s:win2k8dc1 >c:dcdiag.`txt

I receive the following error:

> ```
>   Starting test: VerifyEnterpriseReferences
>
>      The following problems were found while verifying various important DN
>
>      references.  Note, that  these problems can be reported because of
>
>      latency in replication.  So follow up to resolve the following
>
>      problems, only if the same problem is reported on all DCs for a given
>
>      domain or if  the problem persists after replication has had
>
>      reasonable time to replicate changes. 
>         [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
>
>          Base Object: CN=WIN2K8DC1,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=JEWELS,DC=LOCAL
>
>          Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
>
>          Value Object Attribute Name: msDFSR-ComputerReferenceBL
>
>          Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
>
>          Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862
>
>
>         [2] Problem: Missing Expected Value
>
>          Base Object: CN=WIN2K8DC2,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=JEWELS,DC=LOCAL
>
>          Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
>
>          Value Object Attribute Name: msDFSR-ComputerReferenceBL
>
>          Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
>
>          Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862
>
>
>         LDAP Error 0x20 (32) - No Such Object. 
>      ......................... WIN2K8DC1 failed test
> ```

I have been researching and found a microsoft technet forum post about a similar issue. The answer was to run

```
dfsrmig /getglobalstate
```

and see what state the dc was in.  if the state is start, prepared or redirected you should start the process over again with the following commands:

```
dfsrmig /setglobalstate = 1
dfsrmig /setglobalstate = 2
dfsrmig /setglobalstate = 3
```

to push it through the process. However **getglobalstate** returned: *dfsr migration has not yet initialized. To start migration please set global state to desired value.*

Should I still go through the **setglobalstate** commands, or is this another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at KB article Q312862?  The command output mentions it twice, so that's the very first thing that I'd do.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312862

Also, check out this question and the first answer:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/2ce07c3f-9956-4bec-ae46-055f311c5d96/

Comment: that is the technet question I was originally referring too. However I can not edit the msDFSR-CompterReferenceBL attribute, the second answer below that explain the dfsrmig /setglobalstate but I was curious about the process..